# Does linearization interfere with analysis of chaotic behavior?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

If one has a nonlinear 3+ system of differential equations, then it is linearized, is the linearization capable of accurately portraying the chaotic behavior in some manner?

Answer (score 1):

No, the solutions to linear (ordinary) differential equation systems are known. They are not chaotic (also see [this question on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404309/36360)). Non-linearity is a precondition for chaos in a finite dimensional system.

Comment: I added the finite dimensional assumption since infinite dimensional, linear systems can [display chaos](https://feldman.academic.wlu.edu/files/pdffiles/LinearChaos.pdf).